# Where is located managed disk after convertion?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-disk

Help me to understand.
I created a VM of Windows OS with a regular VHD disk.
Then I converted it to a managed disk.
My original VHD is located at Resource Group -> Account Storage -> Containers -> vhds folder.
I can't find my new managed disk. Where is he located ?
I can't find any information in Azure portal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview)

> Azure managed disks are stored as page blobs, which are a random IO
> storage object in Azure

So it will be residing in your storage account configured

Comment: Thanks. I found it in my Resource Group. Thanks